# Passing interface{} or []interface{} in Golang

Tags: go, interface

With this snippet, why does it allow interface{} to pass into the function but not []interface. And what's the difference? I know what the error says (have commented it into the function), but I'm not sure what the error means.

https://play.golang.org/p/689R_5dswFX

```
package main

type smsSendRequest struct {
    Recipients     string `json:"recipients"`
}

// func action(pass interface{}) {
//     //works
// }

func action(pass []interface{}) {
    //cannot use data (type *smsSendRequest) as type []interface {} in argument to action
}

func main() {
    to := "15551234567"
    var data = &smsSendRequest{
        Recipients:     to,
    }
    action(data)
}
```

Comment: `[]interface{}` isn't an interface itself, it's a slice. `*smsSendRequest` is not a slice of empty interface, so you can't pass it as an argument.

Comment: Thanks Jim, is there a way to rewrite this so I can pass it as an argument? Or should I just have the pointer in the function instead? I was trying to avoid that so I could easily reuse the function for other arguments.

Comment: What was wrong with the `interface{}` type? If you want to accept _any_ type, that's what you use.

Comment: `interface{}` (empty interface) is satisfied/implemented by *every type* in Go (including `smsSendRequest`). `[]interface{}` is a *slice* of empty interfaces which is "satisfied" by only itself, and *nothing else*. Your code snippet doesn't suggest any requirement for the slice nor for the interface. Just specify the concrete type.

Comment: Note if you want one _or more_ arguments, you can use a variadic function, but that's a different issue from whether you want an interface{} or not.

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the use of the generic `interface{}`, maybe look into creating a custom interface that supports the methods required by the action function, even though that function is not exported, it just makes things a lot more comfortable in the long run. Then you can use the function for any type that implements your defined interface, supporting your desire for code reuse. made a small example here: https://play.golang.org/p/QJo04XPY5dx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type `interface{}` can be used as a very generic type that would allow any other type to be assigned to it.

So if a function receives `interface{}`, you can pass any value to it.

That is because in Go, for a type to satisfy an interface it must just implement all methods the interface declares.

Since `interface{}` is an empty interface, any type will satisfy it.

On the other hand, for a type to satisfy `[]interface{}` it must be an actual slice of empty interfaces.

So if you need a generic function that can receive any value, just use `interface{}` as you show in your example.

Note that `interface{}` will allow you to pass in either value or pointer references, so you can pass in pointers or values indistinctly to that function.